# Orbeon server gives different responses under stress

Tags: orbeon

I got a really strange issue that happened during stress tests.

This is a search form, the user searches for an object in a popup, select it (click on a checkbox), validate (a trigger in a popup) and the selection is copied on the main page.

This usually works. But when orbeon is under a lot of stress (lots of clients doing this operation at the same time) the server response is sometimes different.

If the user waits for two seconds before validating the selection, it works.

Request:

```
<!DOCTYPE xxforms:event-request [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>
<xxforms:event-request xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xxforms:static-state>pers:C9B10DD4-DD1B-11F4-907F-1102C7BD8015</xxforms:static-state>
    <xxforms:dynamic-state>pers:67DD2321-B039-300B-F048-6FE05A18E044</xxforms:dynamic-state>
    <xxforms:action>
        <xxforms:event name="DOMFocusOut" source-control-id="xf-12$advancedSearchControl$basic-input"></xxforms:event>
        <xxforms:event name="DOMFocusIn" source-control-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$mainselect•1"></xxforms:event>
        <xxforms:event name="xxforms-value-change-with-focus-change" source-control-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$mainselect•1">197552cfa69416449f209b70ba3f8bb6@domain.com</xxforms:event>
    </xxforms:action>
</xxforms:event-request>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xxf:event-response xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xxf:dynamic-state>pers:415194AF-12B7-C579-5A81-98D7935D5001</xxf:dynamic-state>
    <xxf:action>
        <xxf:control-values>
            <xxf:control id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$selected-input-multiple">
                        197552cfa69416449f209b70ba3f8bb6@domain.com
                        197552cfa69416449f209b70ba3f8bb6@domain.com
            </xxf:control>
            <xxf:control id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$mainselect•1">
                197552cfa69416449f209b70ba3f8bb6@domain.com</xxf:control>
            <xxf:control id="xf-12$xf-49" readonly="false"/>
        </xxf:control-values>
    </xxf:action>
</xxf:event-response>
```

But if the user waits for 5 seconds instead. Same request, different response, and the selection is not reported in the main page.

Request:

```
<!DOCTYPE xxforms:event-request [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>
<xxforms:event-request xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xxforms:static-state>pers:C9B10DD4-DD1B-11F4-907F-1102C7BD8015</xxforms:static-state>
    <xxforms:dynamic-state>pers:57740724-BFBE-D1FB-C7D4-2E586711B13B</xxforms:dynamic-state>
    <xxforms:action>
        <xxforms:event name="DOMFocusOut" source-control-id="xf-12$advancedSearchControl$basic-input"></xxforms:event>
        <xxforms:event name="DOMFocusIn" source-control-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$mainselect•1"></xxforms:event>
        <xxforms:event name="xxforms-value-change-with-focus-change" source-control-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$mainselect•1">197552cfa69416449f209b70ba3f8bb6@domain.com</xxforms:event>
    </xxforms:action>
</xxforms:event-request>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xxf:event-response xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xxf:dynamic-state>pers:67DD2321-B039-300B-F048-6FE05A18E044</xxf:dynamic-state>
    <xxf:action>
        <xxf:control-values>
            <xxf:control id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$mainselect•1"/>
        </xxf:control-values>
        <xxf:script name="xf_12_displaySearchResults_datatableMultiple_xf_231_xforms_function" target-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$xf-229" observer-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$xf-229"/>
        <xxf:script name="xf_12_displaySearchResults_datatableMultiple_xf_256_xforms_function" target-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$repeat-header" observer-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$repeat-header"/>
        <xxf:script name="xf_12_displaySearchResults_datatableMultiple_xf_205_xforms_function" target-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$fr-dt-group" observer-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$datatableMultiple-container"/>
        <xxf:script name="xf_12_displaySearchResults_datatableMultiple_xf_231_xforms_function" target-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$xf-229" observer-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$xf-229"/>
        <xxf:script name="xf_12_displaySearchResults_datatableMultiple_xf_256_xforms_function" target-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$repeat-header" observer-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$repeat-header"/>
        <xxf:script name="xf_12_displaySearchResults_datatableMultiple_xf_362_xforms_function" target-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$line-repeat" observer-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$line-repeat"/>
        <xxf:script name="xf_12_displaySearchResults_datatableMultiple_xf_362_xforms_function" target-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$line-repeat" observer-id="xf-12$displaySearchResults$datatableMultiple$line-repeat"/>
        <xxf:setfocus control-id="xf-12$advancedSearchControl$basic-input"/>
    </xxf:action>
</xxf:event-response>
```

In the case it fails, repeating the operation a second time will fail again, the third will be ok.

The tester is a customer tool that automates requests to the server, but the issue appears also if one tries the operation manually (while the server is under stress by the tester).

It's hard to tell when it occurs during the automatic tests, but doing it manually while ther server is busy, the result is systematic.

- if you validate directly it works, if you wait about 5 seconds it fails
- if it fails, it fails twice, works on the third

So, what can make the server answer differently ? I can guess what the right response does, that looks like what it is supposed to do.

I've no idea what the wrong response is supposed to be, there is no  action anywhere in my form or my xbls.

What can I do to solve this, or at least find more info on what's happening ?

Orbeon version: 3.8.0.201005141856 CE

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have to say the following as it's not very helpful, but since we are talking about a version of Orbeon Forms which is almost 5 years-old, it's going to be hard to figure out. There might have been bugs in that version which (hopefully) have been fixed in the many releases of the software since then.

Since the software is open source, you can get the source and try to debug, although it might be a bit challenging as it's a non-trivial piece of software.

Comment: I guessed you wouldn't have a straight answer, but I hoped it was maybe something that happened to somebody else. Any pointers on where to start ?

Comment: Very hard to provide an answer. It seems like pretty involved debugging. I would try to use logging, a debugger, etc. The requests are meant to reach a class called `XFormsServer`, which you can see as of Orbeon Forms 3.8 [here](http://goo.gl/yg1cSG). After that quite a bit goes on as far as state handling, and reaching the [`XFormsContainingDocument`](http://goo.gl/ykijWr), which in turn holds models, instances, and controls. The Ajax response comes from [ControlsComparator](http://goo.gl/m6GrWp).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to see what I can do with that. I'll update in case I find something.